# Android equivalent of iOS' SFSafariViewController

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, sfsafariviewcontroller

On iOS, there are **3** ways to display web content (as I was told by a iOS dev):

1. a `UIWebView` displayed inside a `UIControllerView` if I am correct
2. a `SFSafariViewController` as a `UIControllerView`
3. `Safari`, the app itself

on Android, as far as I am concerned, there are only two ways :

1. a `WebView` (inside a `Fragment` or `Activity` layout)
2. the user default browser app, if any, (usually Chrome, but you know anything that can handle the `Action.View` `Intent`).

Anyway, the advantage of the `SFSafariViewController` is that you have a full-fledged web browser in your app without leaving your app with a constant UX across the entire OS.

Recently, I came across apps such as Reddit or the French railway app (OuiSNCF) where web content are displayed in a manner that looks definitely like the `SFSafariViewController` on iOS :

- it is displayed in separate  on top your current `Activity`
- it shows the URL and if it is secured
- and the three dots menu icon says, at the bottom of the dialog upon touch, "Provided by Chrome" (if I am correct as my phone is in French).

But looking on the internet and here on SO, I can only find ways to launch Chrome itself via Intents.
Looking for `ChromeView` I stumbled on some projects, nothing official.

So here I am asking this question: is this official in any way ? Is there really a sort of `ChromeWebView` similar to that of the `SFSafariViewController` on iOS ? If yes, how can it be implemented ?

Thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is indeed an official way : `Chrome Custom Tabs` as detailed here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes You can achieve this by using `CustomTabs`

Add this to your `app/build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {

      implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
}
```

> For Java

```
String url = "https://paypeg.me/";
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

> For Kotlin

```
val url = "https://paypeg.me/"
           CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
           .build()
           .launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url))
```

More customisation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/)