# how to detect whether website is running in "android Custom Tabs" or "Safari View Controller"

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, browser

This is question talks about those mentioned techniques:
[Android equivalent of iOS' SFSafariViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608517/android-equivalent-of-ios-sfsafariviewcontroller)

There is browser windows that open within the app:

1. IOS: SFSafariViewController
2. Android: Chrome Custom Tabs

My website unfortunately only functions in a fully opened browser app. A lot of my users enter my app through either of the two above mentioned in-app-browser-windows. If they did, I want to notify my users of that, since they would be experiencing a broken website, that they should switch to the actual safari/chrome app.

I am actually using the Ionic Framework in my website, but I don't think the Platform.is() includes any method to detect this.

How do I detect this? Maybe through user agent or something similar?